# Is there a difference between <winsock.h> and <winsock2.h>?

Tags: c++, winsock

I'm including  as it's required by the MySQL C library.

The auto-complete in VS2010 is also showing a  - any idea what this is?

Are they interchangeable, and are there any advantages of one over the other?

Thanks!

Answer (score 37, accepted):

@cost's answer [links](http://cboard.cprogramming.com/networking-device-communication/71596-winsock-vs-winsock2.html) to a discussion that, amongst other things, asks this question that was never answered:

> Is there a reason why I can't include windows.h before winsock2.h, it gives me tons of errors, but once I switch their order everything is okay... why is that?

`windows.h` includes `winsock.h` by default (if `WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN` is not defined).  The problem is not limited to just `windows.h`, though.  Any time `winsock.h` gets included before `winsock2.h`, there will be compiler errors.

The reason is because the two files **DO NOT** co-exist very well.  `winsock2.h` was designed to **replace** `winsock.h`, not extend it.  Everything that is defined in `winsock.h` is also defined in `winsock2.h`.

If `winsock2.h` is included before `winsock.h`, `winsock2.h` defines `_WINSOCKAPI_` to prevent the compiler from processing subsequent `winsock.h` includes, and all is fine.

But if `winsock.h` is included before `winsock2.h`, `winsock2.h` does not detect that  and tries to re-define everything that `winsock.h` has already defined, causing the compile to fail.

You have to be very careful when mixing code that uses `winsock.h` with code that uses `winsock2.h` in the same project.  For instance, when writing your own socket code that uses `winsock2.h`, and using third-party libraries that still use `winsock.h`.

Comment: "`windows.h` includes `winsock2.h` when compiling for newer Windows versions" - Where can I actually see this? I opened `Windows.h` from the Windows 10 19041 SDK, and it always fixedly includes the old `winsock.h` - and I get the compilation errors you mentioned when manually including `WinSock2.h` afterwards.

Comment: @Ray you are correct. The stock `windows.h` includes only `winsock.h`. My compiler's vendor modified their bundled copy of `windows.h` to include `winsock2.h` instead. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you so much. Great to see people maintaining their 10+ year old answers :)

Answer (score 9):

You should use `winsock2.h` unless you want to use Winsock 1.1. `winsock2.h` is for Winsock 2.

You can read more about it at the [Wikipedia Winsock page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winsock#Implementations).

Answer (score 0):

Winsock2 is completely backwards compatible with the original winsock, so the only reason you would ever want to use the original winsock is when you are targeting a platform that doesn't support winsock2 (Everything that is newer than Windows 3.11 supports winsock2 I believe).