# Error : MFC requires use of Winsock2.h after migrating Visual C++ project to Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, mfc

After migrating a project from Visual C++ to Visual Studio 2013 I receive the following error on building the project:

`C1189:#error: MFC requires use of Winsock2.h`

In `stdafx.h` I've included the following headers:

```
#include <afxwin.h> 
#include <afxext.h>
#include <afxdtctl.h>
#include <afxcmn.h>
#include <afxsock.h>
#include <WinSock2.h>
```

I've tried to change the order of the include files ( winsock before and after MFC headers ) but still the same errors.

Can anyone give me some ideas to solve this issues ? Thank you !

Comment: Read the error message again, doesn't it say "winsock**2**.h"?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14094457/winsock-h-winsock2-h-which-to-use

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I've forgot to specify: I've included `winsock2.h` instead of `winsock` but I still have the same errors.

Comment: 1.  Edit the question to show <winsock2.h> rather than <winsock.h>.  2.  Have you tried a "rebuild all " after changing stdafx.h?  3.  Have you checked that nothing else is including <winsock.h>?

Comment: 1. Done 2. Yes. I've tried rebuild all 3. Yes, I've checked and nothing else is including <winsock.h>

Answer (score 3):

Solved ! One of the .cpp files from Extern dependencies was including `<winsock.h>`. I've removed the include line and the problem was solved. Thank you !